# Compute smoothed probabilities for EM algorithm

Tags: probability, markov-process, expectation-maximization

In order to compute the expected value of log-likelihood in EM algorithm, we use 3 different probabilities

1. Forecast (predictive) probabilities
2. Inference probabilities
3. Smoothed probabilities

The most important one is this smoothed probabilities which are computed conditional on having the information about the whole sample.

[image: Table of examples]
As an example of computed smoothed probabilities, I have attached the image where in 3rd column the smoothed probabilities are computed.

Anyone can help to understand just in one  example how one gets them?

Table is taken from Erik Kole
Econometric Institute, Erasmus School of Economics, Erasmus University Rotterdam

Comment: Is this table yours or someone else´s? In the second case, you should indicate the author and the origin of the table.

Comment: Please tell us what "Kim (1994)" refers to--or, better yet, describe this smoother in detail.

Comment: I have removed this "Kim (1994)" as it is not really important. The ones who are familiar with this EM algorithm are able to compute them. I know how do compute the probabilities in first two columns, but not in the last column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, the algorithm is:
$$
\widehat{\xi}_{t \vert T} = \widehat{\xi}_{t \vert t} \odot \left\lbrace P \times \left[ \widehat{\xi}_{t+1 \vert T}  (\div)  \widehat{\xi}_{t+1 \vert t}  \right] \right\rbrace
$$
where $\widehat{\xi}_{t \vert T} = (P(S_t = 0 \vert y_{1:T}; \theta), P(S_t = 1 \vert y_{1:T}; \theta))'$ is the (2x1) vector of smoothed probabilities, \odot is the Hadamard product and $(\div)$ denotes element-wise division. $P$ is your transition matrix. Note that the notation here assumes that the rows! must sum to one (sum authors use the transpose of this matrix). Once $\widehat{\xi}_{T \vert T}$ is obtained from the Hamilton filter for $t=T$, The algorithm can then be iterated backwards for $t = T-1$ to $t=1$. $\widehat{\xi}_{t+1 \vert t}$ refers to a forecast probability, $\widehat{\xi}_{t \vert t}$ is the inference probability. Below is some code, you should be able to read it even if you do not know matlab.

```
    for tt = (T-1):-1:1 % smooth probabilities
        psmooth(:,tt)=pfilter(:,tt).*(P*(psmooth(:,tt+1)./ppredict(:,tt+1)));
    end
```

EDIT: Here is one example for observation 9, State 0. The code could be rewritten as:

```
    psmooth0(9)=pfilter0(9)*(p11*psmooth0(10)/ppredict0(10) + (1-p11)*psmooth1(10)/ppredict1(10));
```

Which gives 0.00038*(0.8*0.05800/0.20023+(1-0.8)*0.94201/0.79977) = 0.00018

You may try to get the same probability for State 1 yourself.

Note that ten is not the full length of the data set, because for the last data point smoothed probabilities and inference probabilities must be the same, which obviously is not the case in the table. Also another remark: You do NOT! need the smoothed probabilities for computing the log-likelihood as you write above.

Comment: I have seen this formula and could not use. My question was to just pick one number from this table and show step-by -step how it is done. There are packages that run the EM algorithm without even coding. I really need to understand how can I compute them by hand

Comment: Added one example to my answer above.

Comment: I thought I need those smoothing probabilities to compute the expected log likelihood for the expectation step

Comment: That's true there are some instances of EM that build on smoothed probabilities. If you attempt to maximize the log-likelihood directly you not need smoothed probabilities. Anyway you should know how to compute them now! Let me knwo if you need more details.

Comment: could you please explain how do we use the next smoothed probabilities to compute the previous one? ok, in this table they are given, but what about if do not have this data? is it because, as you said, the last inference probabilities should be the same as smoothed probabilities, so we use this last one to compute the previous ones?

Comment: You set the last smoothed probability equal to the last inference probability and then you go backwards each period at a time, starting with the second last period.